# to use `async fn`, switch to Rust 2018 or later

Tags: rust, compilation, lib

I'm trying to compile a lib in rust and I get the following error:

```
to use `async fn`, switch to Rust 2018 or later
```

This is my cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "name"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
```

and to compile I use the following command line (documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/crates/lib.html)):

```
rustc --crate-type=lib src/apis/my_file.rs
```

does anyone have an idea?

Comment: use `cargo build` not `rustc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name implies `Cargo.toml` is interpreted by `cargo`, not `rustc` if you want to compile with `rustc` you have to add the edition flag:

```bash
rustc --edition=2018 --crate-type=lib src/apis/my_file.rs
```

Comment: I would add that, for **most** (if not all at this point) projects, cargo should be preferred, since it handles all of these arguments for you (+ dependency management). Especially so since OP has a `Cargo.toml`